# System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property 'Value' on the target control

Tags: binding, user-controls

I have developped light UserControl with some properties that support binding Like that

```
public class EditDateTimeBox : UserControl,IKeyboardNavigation
{

    private TextBox textBox;

    private MonthCalendar monthCalendar = new MonthCalendar();
    ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
    ToolStripControlHost host;
   //.....
   [Bindable(true)]
    public DateTime Value{get;set;}
 }
```

but whene i try to bind it like that:

```
    bool _binded = false;
    string _dataColumn ;
    [Category("OverB")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string DataColumn
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataColumn;

        }
        set
        {
            _dataColumn = value;
            if (!_binded && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_dataColumn) && _dataSource != null)
            {
                this.DataBindings.Add("Value", DataSource, _dataColumn,true);
                _binded = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

an error thrown say:
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property 'Value' on the target control

when i debug with dotnet support, i found that the Binding class(System.Windows.Forms) in the ChechBinding() method cause the problem
here is the code with comment

```
// If the control is being inherited, then get the properties for
            // the control's type rather than for the control itself.  Getting
            // properties for the control will merge the control's properties with
            // those of its designer.  Normally we want that, but for 
            // inherited controls we don't because an inherited control should 
            // "act" like a runtime control.
            //
            InheritanceAttribute attr = (InheritanceAttribute)TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(control)[typeof(InheritanceAttribute)];
            if (attr != null && attr.InheritanceLevel != InheritanceLevel.NotInherited) {
                propInfos = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(controlClass);
            }
            else {
                propInfos = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(control);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < propInfos.Count; i++) {
                if(tempPropInfo==null && String.Equals (propInfos[i].Name, propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    tempPropInfo = propInfos[i];
                    if (tempPropIsNullInfo != null)
                        break;
                }
                if(tempPropIsNullInfo == null && String.Equals (propInfos[i].Name, propertyNameIsNull, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    tempPropIsNullInfo = propInfos[i];
                    if (tempPropInfo != null)
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (tempPropInfo == null) {
                throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.ListBindingBindProperty, propertyName), "PropertyName");
```

Any idea?

Comment: In the method(dotnet) CheckBinding(), there are some casting from my control to IBindableComponent, for this reason, my new property it dosn't exist!...  private IBindableComponent control;  propInfos = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(control); any idea!!!!

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i found the problem, the error is purly mine, here is the zomby code

public new  ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings { get { return textBox.DataBindings; } }

sorry